# is there any way to store ajax request between pages

Tags: ajax

say i have page A, that uses ajax to call students names list

can i cache it in a way that say tomorrow the user opens page B that also using the same ajax to the same list? like the way the browser uses cache for files (JS CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the resource you call with Ajax set the relevant caching headers. The browser will automatically cache them like it does with images.

http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: seems like it, i'll test it and if so i'll vote and set answer

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

Comment: sry m8, not what i needed

Comment: So explain deeply your issue, because it seems to fit what you asked for.

Comment: the locale storage is based on the window object, therefor when i close my browser and re-open it and go to another page and ajaxing the  same content it wont help. the Global Storage could help but IE doent support it

Comment: You mistake LocalStorage for SessionStorage. LocalStorage is persistent, just like GlobalStorage (which, as you pointed, is not standard). If retro-compatibility is an issue for you, you can use cookie instead, or a wrapper library that will use either cookie or LocalStorage if there are available.